# CloudWatch Alarm on Specific Group of Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I have 50 instance running in a specific region. I have to add a Billing Alarm on only 10 instances from the group of 50 instances.

I don't know whether it is possible or not because the billing can only be applied on all the instances, not on some specific instance.

Is there any way to do it by editing the metric source to filter the required instance?

Thanks!

Comment: I think a possibility could be through AWS Budgets. You could create a budget based on a resource tag (common tag for the instances of interest) and then set the alarm on the budget created. Using plain billing metric data can only go down to a service level as you noted.